# Convert Columns to Rows every nth value in pandas and join with a comma

Tags: python, pandas

**Here is what I have:**

```
data = np.array([np.arange(1000)]*2).T

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['a','b'])



    a   b
0   0   0
1   1   1
2   2   2
3   3   3
4   4   4
... ... ...
995 995 995
996 996 996
997 997 997
998 998 998
999 999 999
```

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

For column `a`, take the first 100th rows, append each row with a comma, add them as a row of their own. Take the next 100 rows. Continue till you exhaust the points in the column. 
Repeat for column `b`

Overwriting the existing column, or creating a new column does not matter.

**Here is what I am trying to make it look like:**

```
       c                   d
0,1,2,3,4,5...99    0,1,2,3,4,5...99
101, 102, 103,...   101, 102, 103,...
```

Comment: Does `df.astype(str).groupby(df.index//100).agg(', '.join)` do what you want?

Comment: @JonClements yes this works to an extent, but breaks if the number of rows is 110 for example. Can it be robust against the number of rows? so it can work for 110, one row will have 100, the next will have 10?

Comment: @JonClements sorry! Disregard my comment for a second !

Comment: @JonClements yes this works perfectly ! Thank you. Please add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you could do:

```
df = df.assign(cut=pd.cut(x=df.a, bins = np.arange(0, len(data)+2, 100)))
```

And for `a` you could do:

```
df['c'] = df.groupby('cut')['a'].transform(lambda x:  ','.join(map(str, x.values.tolist())))
df.drop('cut', axis = 1)

       a    b                    c
0      1    1  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,1...
1      2    2  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,1...
2      3    3  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,1...
3      4    4  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,1...
4      5    5  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,1...
```